# Android ConstraintLayout vertical weight is displayed incorrect

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make a layout which should look like this:

[image: Layout how it should be]

I am currently using ConstraintLayout so I can scale the TextViews with the "weight" attribute. But the TextView on the bottom is causing problems. I've set all constraints how they should be and I've also set every height and width to 0dp and the weigths accordingly.

My code is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_Holiday"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_OffHours"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_SWG"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_Holiday"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/list_KUG"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_KUG"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_Holiday"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/list_ExtraHours"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_SWG"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_ExtraHours"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_OffHours"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/list_SHours"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_KUG"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_OffHours"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_Holiday"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/list_FHours"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_KUG"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_ExtraHours"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_SHours"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_FHours"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_ExtraHours"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_FHours"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_Holiday"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_OffHours"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_SHours"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />
```

which is inside of a ConstraintLayout. The problem is, that the layout is not displayed at all. When I set the height of the TextView at the bottom (textView_Holiday) to "match_parent" or "wrap_content" I can see, that the layout is nearly correctly displayed except of the TextView that I just changed.
I think there are some mistakes with the vertical chains but I can't see, where I did something wrong.

Comment: I put your code to my studio and it works correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check that in your project's build.gradle (Module: app) file, under the dependencies you have included:

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'`

(i.e. the ConstraintLayout's dependency) and then build your project once again.

Also, make sure that the parent layout i.e. ConstraintLayout (as you are using ConstraintLayout) is being given:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

If this doesn't work then post your entire code and I would try my best to help you further.

Comment: Strange... I updated the dependency from 1.0.2 to 1.1.2 and now it's fine. Thank you!